# How do I set the image for VideoCastControllerActivity

Tags: android, google-cast

I am using the default VideoCastControllerActivity when I am casting. I call it via `videoCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity(activity, mediaInfo, 0, true);` however when the VideoCastControllerActivity is visible the image is not set.

How do I populate that image?

[image: VideoCastControllerActivity without image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MediaInfo that you build for your media needs to have two images; the first one (index=0) will be a smaller one that can be used in, say, MiniController or notification, and the second image (index=1) is a larger one for that page and also the lock-screen for more recent versions of Android.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful